# Solving for $u$ in $s = ut + \dfrac{1}{2} at^{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to solve for $u$ in $s = ut + \frac{at^2}{2}$

My steps:

$$s = ut + \frac{at^2}{2}$$

therefore

$$u = \frac{s}{t + \frac{at^2}{2}}$$

is this correct?

Comment: You should have $$s = ut + \frac{at^{2}}{2}$$ $$\implies s - \frac{at^{2}}{2} = ut$$ $$\implies \frac{s - \frac{at^{2}}{2}}{t} = u$$

Answer (score 2):

If $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ then $$u=\frac{s-\frac{1}{2}at^2}{t}$$  You must subtract the $\frac{1}{2}at^2$ term before dividing by $t$.  You can only divide a side of an equation by a term that the whole side is multiplied by.

Answer (score 0):

Mattos and turkeyhundt both showed you correct methods for solving the problem.  Here is a slightly different approach.

\begin{align*}
s & = ut + \frac{at^2}{2}\\
2s & = 2ut + at^2 && \text{multiply both sides of the equation by $2$}\\
2s - at^2 & = 2ut && \text{subtract $at^2$ from each side of the equation}\\
\frac{2s - at^2}{2t} & = u && \text{divide each side of the equation by $2u$}
\end{align*}

This solution is equivalent to that obtained by Mattos and turkeyhundt, which you can see by multiplying both the numerator and denominator of the solution they obtained by $2$.

You made an error when you divided by $t + \dfrac{at^2}{2}$ since $u$ is multiplied by $t$ but not $\dfrac{at^2}{2}$.